# jQuery string with links, add A tags around them.

Tags: jquery, twitter

i'm using the Twitter API and trying to replace any text links with  tags, however I just noticed where i'm going wrong.

Currently i'm using the indices which the API provides you where the link is in the text, however when I replace the first link, the second one is no longer in the same position, how could I account for this?

This is my code so far:

```
//Replace text links with HTML links
var content_replaced = obj.text;

if ((obj.entities['urls']).length > 0) {

    $.each((obj.entities['urls']), function(i, obju) {
        var start = content_replaced.substring(0, obju['indices'][0]);
        var end = content_replaced.substring(obju['indices'][1], content_replaced.length);

        //alert('Start: ' + start + ': ' + 'End: ' + end);

        content_replaced = start + ('<a href="'+obju['expanded_url']+'">'+obju['display_url']+'</a>') + end;

        alert(content_replaced + ': ' + obju['indices'][0] +',' + obju['indices'][1]);
    });
}
```

Comment: Iterate from the last to the first (reverse the order of iteration)?

Comment: Thanks! Didn't think of doing that! Such a simple solutions too...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid the indices of the next links from getting messed up, just iterate through the list in reverse order:

```
//Replace text links with HTML links
var content_replaced = obj.text;

if ((obj.entities['urls']).length > 0) {

    $.each((obj.entities['urls'].reverse()), function(i, obju) {
        var start = content_replaced.substring(0, obju['indices'][0]);
        var end = content_replaced.substring(obju['indices'][1], content_replaced.length);

        //alert('Start: ' + start + ': ' + 'End: ' + end);

        content_replaced = start + ('<a href="'+obju['expanded_url']+'">'+obju['display_url']+'</a>') + end;

        alert(content_replaced + ': ' + obju['indices'][0] +',' + obju['indices'][1]);
    });
}
```